# GIF in if-else statement

Tags: java, android, gif

I am trying to show a gif on the next activity when a button is pressed

Here is my code:

```
if (bringLighter == true){
     prologueOutcome.setText("You chose to bring the lighter.");
     prologueBackground.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
     prologueOutcome.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
} else {
    prologueOutcome.setText("You chose to not bring the lighter.");
}
```

I have no idea how to put the gif for the true condition, I have tried putting it in the xml for the activity but the gif shows up on both conditions.

XML Code:

```
<pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/lighter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can change the `visibility` of lighter `GifImageView` based on condition, refer view in Java and check for condition

```
findViewById(R.id.lighter).setVisibility(bringLighter ? View.VISIBLE else View.GONE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two ways.

1-
Add the image within a RelativeLayout.
Give the layout an Id.
In the code call the layout and the image.
Remove the image from within the layout wherever you want.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
           android:id="@+id/gif_image"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:src="@drawable/lighter"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

JAVA:

```
  View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView gif_image = view.findViewById(R.id.gif_image);

 relativeLayout.removeView(gif_image);
```

2-
remove the part:android:src="@drawable/lighter" from the XML;
Add the image only in the JAVA code.

```
   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
    pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView gif_image =  view.findViewById(R.id.gif_image);



   imageView[ID].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.lighter);
```